# Personnalisation string error when validating email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, journeybuilder, html

I am struggling with an error that appears when I try to validate the email on my journey. Indeed, I keep have this error

[image]

[image]

It seems that something is wrong with my HTML and I do not understand what. I do not have any space in between the string of the ampscript code so I was wondering if it is not the If condition ampscript code that create this error

My HTML code is here :

[image]
Thanks for your help

Comment: in the future please post your code and not an screenshot the issue is [IF(empty(@enaukcourtier) is missing the leading %%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your code has two issues I can see:

`[IF(empty(@enaukcourtier)` is missing the leading %%```

and then

`BrokerEmail__C ] %% Bonjour`  should have no space between ] and %%